# Possible Stacking Orders

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question about how to calculate the total number of stacking combinations possible given a set of constraints.

Specifically, imagine I'm trying to make a linear stack of objects (specifically, a row of tiles in my bathroom). I have 3 colors A, B, C. I don't want to put A next to B. The smallest repeating unit I could make would then be:

ACBC

But say I want 5 tiles in my repeating unit, then I could make:

AACBC, ACBBC, or ACCBC

I don't consider ACBCC, as it is really the same pattern as ACCBC, but backwards.

Say I now have N tiles in my repeating unit. Is there a formulaic way to determine the number of ways to place them?

Comment: What you want is the number of [ternary bracelets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29) of length $n$, subject to the constraint that colors A and B not be adjacent. At the link there’s a formula for the total number, which at least gives you an upper bound.

Comment: In the formula for ternary bracelets referenced by @BrianM.Scott, there are some expressions of the form $3^r$ for various $r$. Those simply count colorings of $r$-long strings with $3$ colors.  For your problem, those will get replaced by legally colored $r$-cycles (in the sum) and legally colored $r$-paths (in the second term).  There are nice expressions for these in terms of the $3\times 3$ adjacency matrix which encodes the legal transitions between colors.  Too late for me right now, but I can provide details later if nobody else does.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence appears in OEIS as [A208716](http://oeis.org/A208716); however, neither a formula nor an asymptotic is given there, so I'll state a very general result (but only sketch the proof).  Suppose you have a bracelet with $n$ charms, and you want to color these with $m$ colors, but only certain colors may appear next to each other.  We capture the restrictions as a symmetric $m\times m$ matrix $M=(m_{ij})$, where
$$m_{ij}=\begin{cases}
  1,& \textrm{if colors $i$ and $j$ are allowed to be adjacent}\\
  0,& \textrm{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
We'll call a string (or necklace or bracelet) *legal* if it satisfies these constraints.  We will call a color *repeatable* if it is allowed to be adjacent to itself.  The matrix $M$ in your example is
$$M=\pmatrix{1&0&1\\0&1&1\\1&1&1};$$
the fact that all colors are repeatable is reflected in the fact that the diagonal of $M$ consists of all $1$'s.

The key fact is Burnside's Lemma: if a finite group $G$ acts on a set $X$, the number of orbits is the average, over elements $g\in G$, of the number of fixed points of $g$:
$$|X/G| = \frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} |{\rm Fix}(G)|.$$
For us, $X$ is the set of "legal" colorings, as determined by $M$, and $G$ is a group of symmetries: for "necklaces" $G$ is the $n$-element cyclic group which rotates the necklace, and for "bracelets" we also consider reflections (turning the bracelet upside down.)  (Bracelets are called "free necklaces" in this [MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Necklace.html).) The orbits are just the equivalence classes of the jewelry under the relevant group action.

We start with necklaces: the number $N(n)$ of inequivalent legal necklaces of length $n$ is
$$N(n)=\frac1n\sum_{d|n}\phi(n/d)l(d),$$
where $\phi$ is the Euler phi-function and $l(d)$ is the number of legal necklaces of length $d$.  But the $(i,j)$ entry of $M^d$ is the number of legal strings of length $d+1$ which start at $i$ and end at $j$, so $l(d)$ is simply the trace of the matrix $M^d$.  In principle you can get a closed form for $l(d)$ by computing the Jordan form of $M$, but in some cases it's easier to note that the sequence $\{l(d)\}$ satisfies a linear recurrence equivalent to the characteristic polynomial of $M$.  (Note that if there are no adjacency restrictions, $M$ is the all-ones matrix, so $l(d)={\rm tr}M^d=m^d$ and the usual necklace formula falls out.)

For bracelets, $G$ also contains $n$ reflections. If $n$ is odd, all the reflections have a unique fixed point; if $n$ is even, then half the reflections have $2$ fixed points and the rest have none.  So the bracelet formulas are a little more complicated.  Here's the general result: if $B(n)$ denotes the number of inequivalent legal bracelets, then
$$B(n)= \frac12N(n)+\begin{cases}
  \frac12 s\left(\frac{n+1}2\right),& n{\rm\ odd}\\
  \frac14 p\left(\frac{n}2+1\right) + \frac14 b\left(\frac{n}2\right),& n {\rm\ even,}
\end{cases}
$$
where $p(n)$ is the number of legal strings of length $n$, $s(n)$ is the number of legal strings of length $n$ ending at a repeatable color, and $b(n)$ is the number of legal paths of length $n$ which both begin *and* end at a repeatable color.  (In your special case, $b(n)=s(n)=p(n)$ since all colors are repeatable.)  In any case, these are all easily expressible in terms of $M$: if $\bf j$ is a column vector of $1$'s, and if $\bf r$ is the column vector with $r_i=1$ iff color $i$ is repeatable, then
$$\begin{align}
  p(n)&={\bf j}^t M^{n-1} {\bf j}\\
  s(n)&={\bf j}^t M^{n-1} {\bf r}\\
  b(n)&={\bf r}^t M^{n-1} {\bf r}
\end{align}
$$
In particular, they satisfy the same recurrence as $l(n)$.

OK, specializing to your problem now: the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is
$z^3-3z^2+z+1,$ with roots $1$, $1+\sqrt2$ and $1-\sqrt2$.  We find
$$\begin{align}
  l(n)&=\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^n+\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^n+1\\
  p(n)=s(n)=b(n)&=\frac{1}{2}
   \left(\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^{n+1}+\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{n+1}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Note $l(n)=3l(n-1)-l(n-2)-l(n-3).$

Plugging these into the formulas for $N(n)$ and $B(n)$ we can now count inequivalent legal bracelets:

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 3 & 5 & 7 & 12 & 18 & 34 & 56 & 111 & 207 & 427 & 859 & 1851 & 3930 & 8672 & 19092
   \\
\end{array}
$$

Asymptotically, it is clear that the dominant term is the $d=n$ term in $N(n)$, so
$$B(n)\sim \frac{(1+\sqrt2)^n}{2n}$$
for large $n$.

Finally, it appears you may be anxious to use all three of your colors.  This count didn't require all the colors to be used, but you can use inclusion/exclusion to get the result in that case.  For any subset $S$ of the colors, let $B_S(n)$ denote the number of bracelets using only colors in $S$ (but not necessarily all of them.)  You can compute these by repeating the calculation with an appropriate submatrix of $M$.  Then the number of inequivalent bracelets using all three colors is:
$$N_{123}(n)-N_{12}(n)-N_{23}(n)-N_{13}(n)+N_1(n)+N_2(n)+N_3(n)-N_\emptyset(n).$$